# Readyboost Zero Cache Reads

Tags: readyboost

Performance monitors says that there are zero cache reads/sec and zero cache read bytes/sec for Readyboost. This means I don't gain from readyboost.

I don't understand. Windows 7 accepted my SD card as readyboost device.

- It allowed me to set it as readyboost
- Event logs show that readyboost find the SD card suitable
- According to performance monitor, there are about 1.2GB data cached in the SD card. Readyboost is writing, it is just not reading!

Any ideas?

UPDATE: The SD card size is 8GB and formatted as exFAT.

UPDATE2: I have 4GB of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

How much RAM do you have?  It will always use that if it is available before it resorts to readyboost so you may simply not need it most of the time.  However you may still benefit from superfetch optimising your boot sequence.

Comment: I have 4GB of RAM. I wasn't aware that superfetch can use readyboost for booth sequence. I thought readyboost cache is deleted every reboot.

Comment: Readyboost cache persists on the device after reboot and is not deleted. It is updated after reboot periodically (I assume to refresh the most commonly-used stuff windows loads at start-up.)

Comment: @rdtsc ReadyBoost cache is explicitly **not** trusted across boots (since anything could happen to it, or to the files cached for that matter, between boots). In fact, each boot creates a new RB encryption key. The previous boot's key is not saved, so the new boot couldn't read the old boot's RB cache even if it wanted to. You may be thinking of ReadyDrive, which uses built-in NVRAM cache on a hybrid hard drive. That is trusted across boots; ReadyDrive's prime purpose is to speed up bootstrap. For more details see the section on the "Store Manager" in Windows Internals, 6th ed.